# R aggregate can't find variable

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to use aggregate but it can't find the index variable.

```
df1 <- iris
agg1 <- aggregate(df1, by = list(Species), FUN = sum, na.rm = T, data = df1)

Error in aggregate.data.frame(df1, by = list(Species), FUN = sum, na.rm = T,  : 
  object 'Species' not found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sum` which variable? If you want all of them, you can do `aggregate(.~Species, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE, data = df1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
agg1 <- aggregate(df1[-5], by=list(df1$Species), FUN=sum, na.rm=T)
agg1
#     Group.1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
#2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
#3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```

Don't forget to take the non-numeric columns out of the aggregate. And specify the column with `df1$Species` or `with(df1, aggregate(df1[-5], by=list(Species)..)`. Also `data=df1` is unnecessary when you are not using the formula approach as in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
detach(df)
```

to release the data column.